# when does nestjs add the user object to the reqest

Tags: http, nestjs, req

when i console.log the req in the middleware there is no user{} in the req

```
@Injectable()
export class MyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log(req);
    next();
  }
}
```

but when i console.log the req on an endpoint  there is one

```
 @Get('me')
  async getMe(@Req() req: Request) {
    console.log(req)
    const res = await this.operatorService.findOneAndPopulate(
      (req['user'] as any)._id,
    );
    return res;
  }
```

so when does nestjs exactly add the user{} that i catch it and manipulate bevor the controller

Comment: see https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary

Answer (score 0):

`user` is *usually* added by passport, which most times is added using `@nestjs/passport` and the `AuthGuard()` guard